# Wireless network adapter will not connect to internet, shows "No Internet, Secured" following uninstall of AT&T Global Network Client

Tags: windows-10, 802.11n, ipconfig

I was attempting to uninstall some programs I wasn't using anymore, among them was AT&T Global Network Client. Since doing that I have not been unable to connect to the internet. All other devices I use are able to connect, so I know it's not the router.

I have tried:

- Uninstalling the network adapter
- running `ipconfig /release`, `ipconfig /renew` (running `ipconfig` in general only states Windows IP Configuration and no other info)
- flushing DNS
- resetting the winsock entries
- pretty much everything else a Google search provides...

I feel like this must be as simple as a setting was changed upon install and I'm just not finding it.

It's also worth noting that I was installing a game on steam, and removing the AT&T Client while it was installing. I then accidentally restarted the PC during install.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When Windows OS gets sufficiently messed up, the quickest fix is often to download the latest ISO an reinstall it, keeping your files.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, I was really hoping to find out what the actual problem is....However I agree it's probably time to throw in the towel and reinstall windows. Thanks for your reply and help.